# Removing quotes from a mongo regex

Tags: javascript, mongodb

How do I get ride of the quotes in the $regex objects below.

```
 { '$or': 
    [ '{"last":{"$regex":"/.*Pat.*/"}}',
      '{"first":{"$regex":"/.*Pat.*/"}}' ],
      thing: 57b713625bf9b85ca824de8c }
```

Below is the approach I took but there must be a better way and it does not work because I can't figure out how to put an expression as the value of an object.

```
for (var key in req.query) {
if (req.query.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
  if (key === '$or') {
    for (var item in req.query[key]) {
      if (req.query[key].hasOwnProperty(item)) {
        req.query[key][item] = JSON.parse(req.query[key][item]);
        for (var x in req.query[key][item]) {
         for (var thereMustBeABetterWayToDoThis in req.query[key][item][x]){
           req.query[key][item][x][thereMustBeABetterWayToDoThis] = req.query[key][item][x][thereMustBeABetterWayToDoThis].replace(/["']/g, "");
         }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Does this word `"$regex"` need to be replaced only in the `$or` key and in the specific object you mentioned? Or do you want to remove quotes from the entire object no matter where `"$regex"` appears?

Comment: Preferably anywhere if there is a simple way to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want a global replacement of `"$regex"` with `$regex` removing the `"`. I think a simpler way can be just stringifying the JSON and then doing a regex replace and then parsing the JSON again. I say simple because I can not confirm that it will be the most efficient in terms of performance or timing.

To give you an example:

```
var test = { '$or': 
[ '{"last":{"$regex":"/.*Pat.*/"}}',
  '{"first":{"$regex":"/.*Pat.*/"}}' ],
  thing: 57 }
var test_string = JSON.stringify(test); //Convert it into a string.

var re = /\\"\$regex\\"/g;
var output = test_string.replace(re,"$regex"); //Do a simple replace 

var outputObj = JSON.parse(output); //Parse the object.

//So now you'd want to work with the outputObj
```

The crux is this regexp - `\\"\$regex\\"`. I have created a basic [demo](https://regex101.com/r/kBDt2G/1) that would explain how this regex works and can also serve as a playground for you to augment this regular expression further to suit your needs.